# Hidden property of the names

Tags: word-property

Group A and B are all U.S. presidents' last names with different exceptions.

Group A: Washington, Adams, Jefferson, Madison, ...(It's all presidents' last names except Polk)

Group B: Washington, Adams, Jefferson, Madison, ... (It's all presidents' last names except Taft and Carter)

For the full list of presidents' last names, you can get them from google.

What's the common property of last names in group A and group B?

I know you can easily find some rules like "does not contain xxx". That's not correct. The common property can't have "NOT".

Comment: I think you might need some more info/rules for as it stand now the property of group A could just be "do not contain the sub string Polk"

Comment: Yes, I'll do that. Actually it's asking what's the hidden rule that makes group A doesn't contain Polk and group B doesn't contain Taft and Carter

Comment: this won't make a difference though. "Cannot contain the letters "polk" next to each other" is a rule that works. Actually just "pol", "olk" or even "lk" might work.

Comment: For what it's worth, Polk is the only name whose letters are in descending alphabetical order.

Comment: wait. do the lists include Donanld D̶u̶c̶k̶ Trump?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer:

> Group A:  everything that does not match regex /lk/
>  Group B:  everything that does not match regex /^.a.t/

Pretty sure that's not what you intend.  This is probably **too broad**.

Comment: I came up with the exact same but didn't post if because 1- it is surely not what he is looking for and 2- president Grant fits rule B :P

Comment: No.  I added the ^ to stop that :)

Comment: ohh. ^ means start of word was it? Gotta brush up on my regex.

Comment: I added some more rules to the answer. It can't have NOT in the property.

Comment: Set of names in A follow the property in which $\forall N \in A, A \ni N$.